# How do I create a valid CGImageSourceRef from an ALAssetRepresentation?

Tags: core-graphics, alassetslibrary, alasset

I'm trying to use `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` to efficiently create a resized version of an image. I have some existing code that does this with images from disk, and now I'm trying to use an image that comes from `ALAssetsLibrary`.

Here's my code:

```m
ALAsset *asset;
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef imageRef = [representation fullResolutionImage];

CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef);
CGImageSourceRef sourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider(provider, NULL);

NSDictionary *resizeOptions = @{
  kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform : @YES,
  kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways : @YES,
  kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize : @(2100) 
};

CGImageRef resizedImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, resizeOptions);
```

The problem is that `resizedImage` is null, and `CGImageSourceGetCount(sourceRef)` returns 0. The data provider *does* have quite a bit of data in it, though, and the data does appear to be valid image data. The `ALAsset` comes from an iPhone 4S camera roll.

What am I missing? Why does `CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider()` create an image source with 0 images?

Comment: By the way, putting the non-object literal `YES` into your dictionary literal is going to go badly. You want `@YES`.

Comment: Oh, true. It's actually kCFBooleanTrue in my code, but I didn't want to show all the casting here. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CGImageSource is for deserializing serialized images, such as JPEGs, PNGs, and whatnot.

`CGImageGetDataProvider` returns (the provider of) the *raw pixel data* of the image. It does not return serialized bytes in some external format. CGImageSource has no way to know what pixel format (color space, bits-per-component, alpha layout, etc.) any given raw pixel data is in.

You could try getting the URL of the asset rep and giving that to `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL`. If that doesn't work (e.g., not a file URL), you'll have to run the image through a CGImageDestination and create a CGImageSource with wherever you put the output.

(The one other thing to try would be to see whether the rep's `filename` is actually a full path, the way Cocoa often misuses the term. But you probably shouldn't count on that.)

Comment: Ah. This makes sense. And indeed, if I get the serialized data from the `ALAssetRepresentation` via `-getBytes:length:offset:error:` and make an image source out of that, it all works fine.

Comment: @BJHomer: Actually, I'd assumed that that returns pixels; if it returns some external format (which makes sense given the existence of `representationForUTI:`), then you probably should just use that.

Comment: @HeathBorders: My guess would be for CGImages you created with a data provider, in case you want to retrieve the data provider you created the image with. But even then, I don't know why you would do that.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you might try is [the asset rep's `CGImageWithOptions:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetRepresentation/CGImageWithOptions%3a).

The documentation *claims* that:

> This method returns the biggest, best representation available, unadjusted in any way.

But it says that about `fullResolutionImage`, too, and I'm not sure why this class would have both methods if they both do the same thing. I wonder if it's a copy-and-paste error.

Try `CGImageWithOptions:` with a bunch of thumbnail-creating options and see what happens.

Comment: This would probably work; in my case, I have existing code that applies the correct options and handles some other processing, so I really just wanted to pass a `CGImageSourceRef` off to that existing code rather than duplicating it. But in another case, this would likely make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Option #3 would be the rep's `fullScreenImage`. Depending on what sort of “thumbnail” you need, it may be cheaper and/or simpler to just use this, which will be no bigger than (approximately) the size of the device's screen.

Answer (score 0):

This can also help...

```
ALAssetRepresentation* rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

NSDictionary* options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform,
                     (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways, 
                     (id)[NSNumber numberWithDouble:400], (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize, 
                     nil];

CGImageRef image = [rep CGImageWithOptions:options];
```

Comment: Could you please add more details about your solution?